# HBase folder structure with data storage mode as s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hbase, phoenix-framework, amazon-emr

I  set up an EMR cluster with HBase and Phoenix for bulk loading data. The storage mode specified is s3.
I want to know where the regions and column families are present in s3 in the root folder? Also what is the general structure of S3 root folder once bulk loading is finished? Can anyone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a general setups (when your HBase data is in HDFS) you should expect to see the following directory structure in HDFS for HBase:

```
/hbase/data/default/TableName/RegionID/ColumFamily
```

This is assuming that your tables have no namespace (otherwise the namespace should be there instead of 'default').

So, in /hbase/data/default you should have many folders, each of which corresponds to your table in HBase.

And in each TableName folder, you should have many folders, each of which corresponds to a single region within that table. (region IDs are usually just long IDs like this: 49920919fc726446ec73c111a99f00f0)

And then, within each region sub-folder, you should have a folder that corresponds to column family.

Finally, within that folder, you will see the actual HFile (once you flush your data).

I doubt this should be any different when your HBase data is in S3 rather than HDFS, but I've never used S3 for that myself. Just browse for the above folder strucutre.